# How to crate a one to many mapped MySQL database with location hubs/all US zip codes?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a database that that has pricing information for the following location "hubs":

```
Long Beach, CA
Oakland, CA
Portland, OR
Seattle, WA
Salt Lake City, UT
Denver, CO
El Paso, TX
Houston, TX
Dallas, TX
Kansas City, MO
Omaha, IA
Minneapolis, MN
Chicago, IL
St. Louis, MO
New Orleans, LA
Memphis, TN
Nashville, TN
Indianapolis, IN
Detroit, MI
Cleveland, OH
Columbus, OH
Cincinnati, OH
Atlanta, GA
Savannah, GA
Jacksonville, FL
Miami, FL
Tampa, FL
Charleston, SC
Wilmington, NC
Norfolk, VA
Baltimore, MD
Newark, NJ
Boston, MA
```

I then need to input all of the 41,702 zip codes in the US and assign them (this is where I need help) to the corresponding hub. I believe this is done by mapping (one to many) but I don't know how to do that. Could someone please give me an example on how to create this database structure? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each location can have many locations, but each zipcode can have only one location.

```
Table location
id: primary key
name......
.....

Table zipcode
id: primary key
location_id foreign key references (location.id)
x
y
.......
```

By placing the link field in the zipcode table, you force things so that a location can only have 1 user. However, a location can have many locations.

MySQL does not know, nor does it need to know if a relationship is 1-1, or 1-many.
No SQL supports many-many relationships, all require an intermediate table which splits a many-many relationship into 2 separate 1-many.

The difference is in the logic that controls the relationships, which is in the code that you write.
A 1-1 relationship is maintained by having the tables share the same primary key.
With the secondary table declaring that PK as a foreign key pointing to the other tables PK.

The direction of the relationship 1 -> many vs many <- 1 is determined by the location of the link field.

Usually, every table has a unique id and the link field is called tablename_id.
The table that has the link field in it is the many sides of the relationship, the other table is on the 1 side.